# Как типизировать объект в зависимости от указанного значения в свойстве?

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Есть общий интерфейс(**SpinnerInterface**) в котором перечислены все допустимые свойства объекта.

Но свойство(**statusCheck**) должно быть обязательным только в случае если **type** будет указан как **progressLoading**

```
interface SpinnerInterface{
  fillParent: boolean;
  type: SpinnerType;
  statusCheck: StatusProgress; // только для type:progressLoading
}

enum SpinnerType {
  blockedPage,
  progressLoading
}
```

Типизация через **Omit** исключает свойство для всех свойств.

```
type ExcludeStatus = Omit<SpinnerInterface, 'statusCheck'>;
```

Я предполагаю что нужно добавить еще какую то обработку перед **ExcludeStatus** но я незнаю в какую сторону нужно копать(*гуглить*).

Буду рад вашим идеям/предположениям/ссылкам.
Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать общий тип с кастингом св-ва + несколько типов, которые расширяют базовый и там прописать условие для динамических полей

[Пример](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygDgSxCYAnAKgTzsKBvAKCmKgCEBBGAUSgF4oByAIwEMBnYBgGiJIAUASgHkA4gKowYAfQAyQ8gBEAkgDkRdRnFQB7AOapgbNjO0sAJkl3cCAXwIEkAFzQAzFgGNcMRy0dg2fDr6hmz4vMQANqYWILoAXFBM2toRwCwgANy29k6uHl6IyGgAPOga8EgoGNjAAHxhJFAuCBERfCwGII4JSSlpmeFQjjUJ6Fl2Dl15nrCFVaTsuMAAHs4gZqEVRajFW1VYOAB0FNT1eDZZuahuM3toAOoIjgAWgXoGRlAraxuzlSV3apHQSicSSWTyZRqM6DNg%20PxsADCz2A7gA1glvL5-G9gkZxvZhjg-ttQvRAQsOFAAD4kqqPF64j5sLIEAD0bKggCIQQDCIIAhECggCYQQCCIIBWECggD4QQBcIFBAIwgosA7CBQYWCgC0gsADCBQOHYpEo9EEdzaEBw7VzNCU4CY82oS0aQiNIlWuloA7AY6UKg8RrNVrtTrdIaoMDAHgTDnc-mSwASIIAOEFlUo1XCggHEQPkS7Xw-zI1Fo5VqzVQQC8IKK%20Ybjaa2DaGa8gsz7jpYtb-qga0yQvbBk7m9s3YcQWIJNI5IpVCJvSRfW0OqBA24Ihww-YjSbHGaW226yEBAhdM9A4DN%208O-QHSRuy6ge6B2Dh5CxxPiFP-bOEvPF7Cs3rcwk8FAouYlhviwC64HYNhAA)

```
enum SpinnerType {
    BASE = 'base',
    PROGRESS_LOADING = 'progressLoading',
}

interface StatusProgress {
    loading: boolean;
}

// Базовый тип
interface Spinner<T = SpinnerType> {
    fillParent: boolean;
    type: T;
}

interface SpinnerBase extends Spinner<SpinnerType.BASE> {};
interface SpinnerWithProgress extends Spinner<SpinnerType.PROGRESS_LOADING> {
    statusCheck: StatusProgress;
}

type Spinners = SpinnerBase | SpinnerWithProgress;

// Тут все ок без св-ва statusCheck
const spinnerBase: SpinnerBase = {
    type: SpinnerType.BASE,
    fillParent: true,
}

// Тут ошибка, что statusCheck св-ва нет
const spinnerWithProgressWrong: SpinnerWithProgress = {
    type: SpinnerType.PROGRESS_LOADING,
    fillParent: false,
}

const spinnerWithProgressRight: SpinnerWithProgress = {
    type: SpinnerType.PROGRESS_LOADING,
    fillParent: false,
    statusCheck: { loading: false }
}
```

Из плюсов, в `switch/case` по `type` тип будет автоматические внутри `case` определяться)